# Neovim no ~/.config/nvim

Tags: linux, vim

I've got Manjaro with `i3wm`. I've installed `neovim` with `sudo pacman -S neovim`. `nvim` command works. But in every tutorial it says that I should have a `~/.config/nvim` directory and bunch of others in it. And actually I don't. Some other say that it may be installed under `$XDG_HOME_CONFIG`. Hmm lets see:

```
[frynio@manjaro ~]$ echo $XDG_HOME_CONFIG

[frynio@manjaro ~]$ ls /usr/share/nvim
runtime
[frynio@manjaro ~]$ ls /usr/share/nvim/runtime
autoload       colors    delmenu.vim  filetype.vim  ftplugin      ftplugof.vim  indent.vim  keymap      macros        menu.vim   optwin.vim  plugin  scripts.vim  syntax  vimrc_example.vim
bugreport.vim  compiler  doc          ftoff.vim     ftplugin.vim  indent        indoff.vim  macmap.vim  makemenu.vim  mswin.vim  pack        print   synmenu.vim  tutor
[frynio@manjaro ~]$ ls ~/.config
autostart  compton.conf  dmenu-recent  epdfview  gtk-3.0  libfm               mimeapps.list  Mousepad  pcmanfm  qupzilla  user-dirs.dirs    volumeicon  xfce4
clipit     dconf         dunst         gconf     hexchat  manjaro-hello.json  morc_menu      nitrogen  qt5ct    ranger    user-dirs.locale  xarchiver
[frynio@manjaro ~]$
```

I mean, I can create `~/.config/nvim` and then create `init.vim` in it. And `neovim` will actually read it. But then I want to install some plugins. I did that:

```
curl -fLo ~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

From the official wiki: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug

Then I did that (in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`):

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/bundle')
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'bling/vim-airline'
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plug 'zchee/deoplete-go', { 'do': 'make'}
Plug 'zchee/deoplete-jedi'
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
" call PlugInstall to install new plugins
call plug#end()
```

This is copied from some guys YT channel. Now I wanted to switch my colorscheme to solarized. So in my `init.vim` I wrote `colorscheme solarized` (it should be installed through plugins), but then it says this:

```
[frynio@manjaro ~]$ nvim
Error detected while processing /home/frynio/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line    1:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'solarized'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I cannot tell what am I doing wrong. Would you guys help me? (other plugins from the list also don't work)

Answer (score 2):

For Neovim thw path to the init file is `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and the path to the Vim-Plug plugins folder should be `~/.local/share/nvim/plugged`. So in order for your packages(plugins) to work do this :

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had to create the ~/.config/nvim directory, since neovim is reading the 'init.vim' file from it that shouldn't be an issue.

The 'solarized.vim' colorscheme file must exist in the ~/.config/nvim/colors directory.

If you copy it from wherever it may currently be into the colors directory, neovim should be able to find it.